# In asyncfileupload check content type

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

In asyncfileupload i want to check zip and rar i try following code

```
    protected void fileUploadComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string type = fileUpload1.ContentType;

    }
```

When i am upload zip or rar file in type variable when i am debug this i get type like "application/octet-stream". How can i check zip or rar file. i can check using javascript but after that how can i upload on server if i am use javascript for checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
HttpPostedFile fileupload1 = context.Request.Files[0];
System.IO.FileInfo fileupload1Info = new System.IO.FileInfo(up.FileName);
string ext = fileupload1Info.Extension;
if(ext!='.zip' || ext!='.rar'){
      //your logic
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but why asp.net return octet instead of Zip or rar

Comment: that is just giving you the file in binary format after you do a stream reading. You can read more about it [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264968) if you making some mistake setting up IIS